# Dispersion between analog and digital signal in optical fiber

Tags: dispersion, fiber-optics

We know that optical fiber is used to transmit data in digital format.As a result, there is either Intermodal or Intramodal dispersion occurring based on the fiber used for communication.
 If an analog signal is used to transmit the data what happens to the signal. Does it undergo dispersion? How is the dispersion of analog signal different from digital one.

Comment: All signals are analog.   Digital is an approximation, and 'noise margin' is the measure of the error of that approximation.

Comment: i would not call a digital signal an "approximation".  what is it approximating?  you can have a digital signal representing data exactly, if the data has a finite number of *"symbols"* or *messages*.

Comment: Light experiences scattering when the dielectric material changes. There are different types of scattering that ultimately produce diffuse lighting based on the particle size and the wavelength(frequency of the signal) look into mie and Rayleigh scattering

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Just look at [this picture](https://ibb.co/qDgj2WD). In reality all "digital" signals are just modulated waves / wave packets. It's true that all signals are analog. It's just an existing agreement, to call all analog signals modulated in a specific way for being able to decode it into data which would have some informational meaning in electronic devices as "digital". But in principle **any** data you send over WiFi, Bluetooth, optical, coaxial cables, modems or whatever,- uses physical information carrier - electromagnetic or other waves, which by nature is analog.

Answer (score 0):

i think *"dispersion"* happens in a transmission line (whether it's copper or fiber-optic) because the wave speed and the wave attenuation in the transmission line is not constant for all frequency components of the signal.

Comment: That is reason dispersion happens in the transmission line. But, I like to know whether dispersion by analog and digital signal is same or is there any difference.

Comment: digital signals are simply analog signals with binary values.  there will be sharp edges in digital signals and Fourier tells us that high frequencies are needed to make sharp edges.  the high frequencies will experience different attenuation and phase velocity in the fiber optic cable than what the low frequencies experience.

Answer (score 0):

A digital signal is just an analog signal that has one of a set of known values, e.g. two values named '0' and '1'. Dispersion happens in the signal, but as long as the distortion is not too big the receiver will know whether a 0 or 1 was transmitted. So the receiver corrects for any dispersion and other distortions. In an analog signal the receiver can not know what was sent, so it has to use the signal as received including any dispersion/distortion.